# How can I replace index.html by a different file in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

When I browse to `http://www.example.com` I want to be redirected to `http://www.example.com/home.html`,

When I browse to `http://www.example.com/index.php` I want to be redirected to `http://www.example.com/index.php`,

How can I do that?

Comment: `when i input www.example.com/index.php it redirect to www.example.com/index.php` What does that mean they are both same?

Comment: I have try to use DirectoryIndex home.html, but when i input www.example.com/index.php it redirect to www.example.com/home.html too, i want redirect to www.example.com/index.php when i input www.example.com/index.php

Comment: Do you have any existing rule or have some CMS/php installed?

Comment: I have install wordpress,thx

Comment: Then post your current .htaccess code in question.

Answer (score 1):

Hy , 
Just add the following line in you   .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex something.html
```

where something.html will be your index page
As an extra note - see this [page](http://support.tigertech.net/htaccess-topic) from docs on how to manage your .htaccess file.

Comment: I have try to use DirectoryIndex home.html, but when i input www.example.com/index.php it redirect to www.example.com/home.html too

Comment: is your home.html at the first level in your server ? if it's inside another folder this won't work

Comment: Yes, it's at the first level

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `DirectoryIndex` command: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

It allows to configure what files are tried when a directory is requested. It also allows to add several options to be tried. This allows flexibility whilst you can still keep control over the options.

Answer (score 0):

When a URL specifying only a directory is requested
eg.: `http://www.domain.com/directory/`

Apache looks for file names by default (in the order they appear):

`index.html
index.htm
home.html
welcome.html`

The `.htaccess` directive `DirectoryIndex` can be used to override this behavior. In your `.htaccess` file, type the following line:

`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`